# Google Play Store crashes

Tags: android

For a few days the Play store is crashing every time I try to open it and I even get the message when I'm not using it.
It's very annoing so I looked for what was going wrong. I looked at the logcat and I found that there was a problem with the finsky.xml file.

```
Couldn't rename file /data/user/0/com.android.vending/shared_prefs/finsky.xml to backup file /data/user/0/com.android.vending/shared_prefs/finsky.xml
```

So I looked to this file with the shell and I found that there is problems with the permissions.

```
lucye:/data/data/com.android.vending/shared_prefs # ls -l
total 156
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a178 u0_a178   151 2019-02-24 14:21 AIA-ContentFilterCache.xml
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a178 u0_a178   145 2019-02-25 03:46 InstantAppFlagUpdated.storedCurrentAccount.xml
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a178 u0_a178   178 2019-02-26 23:01 InstantAppsExperimentManager.activeExperiments.xml
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a178 u0_a178   754 2019-02-27 13:06 cache_and_sync_preferences.xml
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a178 u0_a178   124 2019-02-24 14:21 com.android.vending_preferences.xml
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a178 u0_a178   304 2019-02-27 00:08 com.google.android.gcm.xml
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a178 u0_a178  2505 2019-02-27 00:08 com.google.android.gms.appid.xml
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a178 u0_a178   137 2019-02-24 14:22 device_settings.xml
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a178 u0_a178  1171 2019-02-24 14:22 downloadPreferences.xml
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a178 u0_a178   173 2019-02-27 13:05 event_generator.xml
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a178 u0_a178   133 2019-02-27 13:05 fake_self_update.xml
-r-------- 1 u0_a178 u0_a178 12645 2018-08-09 19:00 finsky.xml
-r-------- 1 root    root    12645 2019-02-27 13:29 finsky.xml.bak
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a178 u0_a178   234 2019-02-24 14:21 instantapps.UserPrefsUpdater.xml
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a178 u0_a178   139 2019-02-25 03:46 lastAccount.xml
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a178 u0_a178   151 2019-02-27 12:34 notification_helper_preferences.xml
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a178 u0_a178   383 2019-02-25 03:46 patchDetectionPreferences.xml
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a178 u0_a178 38206 2019-02-27 00:09 phenotypeConfigurations.xml
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a178 u0_a178  1536 2019-02-27 12:35 primes.xml
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a178 u0_a178    65 2019-02-27 13:06 protected.xml
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a178 u0_a178    65 2019-02-27 00:08 selfupdate_scheduler.xml
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a178 u0_a178  3050 2019-02-27 12:34 vending_preferences.xml
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a178 u0_a178   142 2019-02-24 14:21 verify_app_single_user_settings_shared_prefs.xml
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a178 u0_a178   118 2019-02-24 14:22 verify_apps_global_shared_prefs.xml
```

So I tried to fix the permissions but it wasn't successful.

```
>chown u0_a178:u0_a178 finsky.xml                                              
chown: 'finsky.xml' to 'u0_a178:u0_a178': Operation not permitted

>chmod 660 finsky.xml
chmod: chmod 'finsky.xml' to 100660: Operation not permitted
```

I did all of these commands with the root shell.

Is someone there that have an idea of what going with this file ?

Thank you,
Louis.

Comment: I also tried to modify permissions within the recovery(TWRP)  but I could not success.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I used  :

```
chattr -AacdDijsStu finsky.xml
```

After that I could remove the file so Google play started working normally.